# How to get the same effect with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Hi everyone how to do this effect with Pure Javascript by placing a button on the top of the box and on click add or remove the class to get the same effect as provided in this slide on hover here is my code

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.mainclass {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  ;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #237aba;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.wrap:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="mainclass"></div>
  <div class="overlay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you just want to replace the use of the pseudo-class (:hover) in your css with pure javascript code.
In that case, maybe the following code is a solution.
I hope this helps :-)

```js
var overlay = 0;
function overlayColor(){
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay")[0];
  var btn = document.getElementById("btnOverlay");
  if ( overlay ){
    element.style.height="0%";
    btn.innerText = "add overlay";
    overlay = 0;
  }
  else {
    element.style.height="100%";
    btn.innerText = "remove overlay";
    overlay = 1;
  }
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}

.mainclass {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  ;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #237aba;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnOverlay" onclick="overlayColor()">
  add overlay
</button>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="mainclass"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```